# CameraX PreviewView Screenshot

Tags: bitmap, screenshot, android-bitmap, android-camerax, takesscreenshot

I want to convert CameraX preview to bitmap from previewView. Something similar to textureView.bitmap

I have tried it with a textureview and it works perferctly, i can take a screenshot of the cameraview but the camera is stretched.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PreviewView now supports screenshot by calling PreviewView.getBitmap(). See: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/camera/view/PreviewView#getBitmap()

Comment: Yes i just saw this and changed it accordingly. Thank you for your answer. Cheers.

Comment: How can we add effects like black & white and greyscale in camerax preview?

Comment: @AsthaGarg did you find any solution? if yes please help, I am also trying to apply filters in realtime preview

Comment: Effect feature was not supported by camerax-Google at that time so we delayed this feature's development. You can check CameraEffects API which is in Beta

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the answer in this [link](https://groups.google.com/a/android.com/forum/#!topic/camerax-developers/BU90VlDmbWc)

First set preferred implementationmode to TextureView as below:

```
previewView.preferredImplementationMode = PreviewView.ImplementationMode.TEXTURE_VIEW
```

Then get the bitmap

```
fun getPreviewViewBitmap(width: Int, height: Int): Bitmap? {
    val previewChildView = previewView.getChildAt(0)

    if (previewChildView is TextureView)
        return previewChildView.getBitmap(width, height)

    return null
}
```

Note: I have only tested on a few devices and it works great.

Cheers.

Comment: It should work without the specific implementation mode too.